# Hide the url when post the data

Tags: php, html

I need some help with my code. When I input my name and email in the textbox and click on a submit button, it will display `https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html` in the url bar to post the data to add my name and email in the autoresponder before it will redirect me to `https://www.example.com/watch-video/`.

I want to hide the url of `https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html` to stop displaying in the url bar when I input my name and email in the textbox to click on a submit button to post the data that will redirect me to `https://www.example.com/watch-video/`.

Here is the code:

```
<form name="info_form" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">

<input placeholder="Enter Your Name..." type="text" name="name" id="awf_field" class="elInputIEmail" data-type="extra"/>

<input placeholder="Enter Your Email..." type="text" name="email" id="awf_field" class="elInputIEmail" data-type="extra"/>


<!-- Campaign token -->
<!-- Get the token at: https://app.getresponse.com/campaign_list.html -->
<input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="18oKuC" />
<input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="https://www.example.com/watch-video/"/>
<!-- Forward form data to your page (optional) -->
<input type="hidden" name="forward_data" value="" />
<!-- Add subscriber to the follow-up sequence with a specified day (optional) -->
<input type="hidden" name="start_day" value="0" />
<!-- Subscriber button -->
<input name="submit" id="af-submit-image-416906520" type="image" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" alt="Submit Form" src="http://www.example.com/Images/button-400.jpg" />
</form>
```

I have tried this:

```
<form name="info_form" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" type="hidden">
```

It will not post the data to the autoresponder as it will redirect me to the next page. I need to post the data to the autoresponder to allow me to add my name and email address.

Can you please show me an example how I can hide the url of `https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html` to stop them display in the url bar when I input my name and email to click on a submit button to allow me to post the data to the autoresponder while it will redirect me to the next page?

Comment: Why use .html instead of .php for add_subscriber?

Comment: Do it with ajax,but I suspect this a case of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @MinimumEntropy I have to use html to add the submit button, textboxes for name and emai. I have got no idea how I can use php to post the data while hide it. can you help?

Comment: Use Ajax Post https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp